# Capistrano, SVN repo and webserver in the same machine

Tags: svn, capistrano

I find that Capistrano is "typically" installed on a workstation rather than the server. Is it ok to install Capistrano and subversion in the same server (public-facing web server)? If possible, what are the things to be considered for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You install Capistrano on machines from which you want to control the deployment proccess (run 'cap deploy' etc). Do you really want to run capistrano tasks from the remote webserver (through ssh I guess)? That's why capistrano is typically instaled on the developer's machine(s). It isn't a bad idea to have SVN and webserver on the same machine, though. You can handle svn repo (remote or local) by the `:repository` variable.